# HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently-Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have created a API using djangorestframework, but when i run it in terminal by using **python manage.py runserver** command it shows  "HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently" error.[This the Message which it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bB6V.png)

But the cool thing is , when i run it in browser it displays the data .
[This the result in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrNfG.png)

**I wanted to know had happened in it.**

And in this the POST call also is not working.

Below is the code:

*serializers.py*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            class Meta:
                model = Snippet
                fields = ('title','code',)

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)


def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer


# Create your views here.


class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self,data,**kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type']='application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

@csrf_exempt
def snippet_list(request):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

@csrf_exempt
def snippet_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
    """
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        snippet.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()


class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

301 is not an error, but a redirect. From the command line, you requested a URL without a trailing slash, but your URL patterns expect the slash to be there. Django has a nice [convenience feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#append-slash) to return a redirect in such cases.

Unlike your command-line HTTP client, your browser recognizes the redirect, and then follows up with a second request to the new URL including the trailing slash.

Comment: but @ koniiiik i am unable to POST data on to it, using postman

Comment: You need to post to the URL that includes the trailing slash, the one without the slash will always return a redirect, and ignore the request body.

Answer (score 1):

The effect you are seeing is because your URL is mapped with an ending `/` and the link you are requesting is without the ending `/`. Django by default will try a URL with ending `/`, if it cannot find a match with the requested URL.

This is controlled by the [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#append-slash) setting, which is set to `True` by default:

> When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the
>   patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP
>   redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended. Note that
>   the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be
>   lost.

To fix this problem, change your command to:

```
http http://127.0.0.1:8006/snippets/
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

"By default the URLs created by SimpleRouter are appended with a trailing slash. This behavior can be modified by setting the trailing_slash argument to False when instantiating the router. For example:

```
router = SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `APPEND_SLASH` set to true.  When you go to the endpoint without a slash, it automatically redirects it to the same URL with a slash, resulting in the 301.

[Documentation is here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#append-slash)

Comment: Bah, Ninja'd to it!